# How can i change width and height of element by changing width of browser windows?

Tags: html, css, height, width

I want width and height of my element change at the same time by changing the width of browser windows.
how can i do it?
and if height and width at first didn't have same size how they to be same in end?

Comment: The minimum requirements at SO are, that you'd post the code relevant to the issue in the question itself, and describe the problem in details. What you want your code to do, and what it does instead. Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to change the width and height of an element based on your browser size you will have to give the width and height of that element in terms of percentage.

```
div {
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     }
```

In this case, the width and height of an element will auto-adjust based on the browser dimensions.